# How should I import components inside the components folder?

Tags: reactjs, import

I have some files in my components folder. Two of them are `CardItem-component/CardItemComponent.js` and `list-component/list-components.js`.
When I'm trying to import the first component into the latter using

```
import CardItemComponent from "./CardItem-component/CardItemComponent";
```

it gives the following mistake:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './CardItem-component/CardItemComponent' in 'D:\project\src\components\list-component'
```

Comment: which IDE are you using? most IDE should add your import address automatically when you use your component in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import CardItemComponent from "./CardItem-component/CardItemComponent";
```

Comment: The matter is it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have given the correct file path and exported the component

```
export default CardItemComponent
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your explanation of your file structure, maybe you are targeting the wrong directory.

```
import CardItemComponent from "../CardItem-component/CardItemComponent";
```

I'm guessing your file structure is:

- /some-folder

  - /CardItem-component

    - CardItemComponent.js
  - /list-component

    - list-components.js

When you are importing `CardItemComponent.js` from `list-components.js`, you need to go up one directory level to access the `/CardItem-component` folder, so you will need to prepend your path with `../`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it was inattentive me. It works well, I only mistyped a few things.